# NestedScrollview inside a Recycler view not scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating an Android program. In this program, I have a ScrollView inside of which there is a  RecyclerView. I am adding data in this RecyclerView via a RecyclerViewAdapter.

For each item of the RecyclerView, there is a NestedScrollview having a single LinearLayout of vertical orientation. I am dynamically adding ImageView in this LinearLayout.

The problem is that the images are not scrolling. In very rare scenarios (by tapping so many times on screen), it got scrolled for once.

Could anybody help me on this?

Here is the code -

Parent Recycler View :-

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/id_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/gray3"
        android:dividerHeight="5sp"
        android:paddingLeft="2sp"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:paddingRight="2sp"/>
        <com.app.sh.widget.WrappedGridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:numColumns="2">

        </com.app.socialhand.widget.WrappedGridView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And the Item of the Recycler View :-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/vScrollView"
              android:layout_below="@id/iv_up"
              android:layout_above="@+id/iv_down"
              android:isScrollContainer="true"
              >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
              <LinearLayout
                  android:id="@+id/ll_123"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  >

              </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
          </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I am dynamically adding the ImageViews in ll_123.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView or remove it. RecyclerView has own scrollview which will conflict with ScrollView.

Comment: I tried with Nested ScrollView too, but it is still not working . Without any scrollview the recycler view is not scrolling at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a structure like:

```
<ScrollView>
    <NestedScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
            <RecyclerView/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </NestedScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

And ListItem layout should contain:

```
<NestedScrollView>
    <LinearLayout/>
</NestedScrollView>
```

Check if this works correctly...

Comment: Thanks chintan for you reply.  But the logic is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got simmilar problem and this helped me:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/messages_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/send_panel"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/messages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have change the the recycler's item's layout as per you code, but it is not working. On Making recycler's item as ScrollView instead of NestedScrollView, the parent list begin to scroll while trying to scroll the child list.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <-only one layout in nestade layout-> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_edit_existing_location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rcl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <-put here yr second layout code->


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Didnt getting your suggest code madhav. Could you more elaborate it.